# how can I display an image and some text to the right of the image in an xml Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have a view which currently displays an image and some text below it. How can I change this so that the text is displayed to the right of the image and not below the image 
This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >



   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical">
      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/icons"
         android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:layout_height="60dp"
         android:padding="5dp" />

      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/item"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:padding="2dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icons"
         android:layout_alignTop="@id/icons"
         android:textColor="#33CC33" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `android:orientation="horizontal" in your second layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:orientation="horizontal"` in your second LinearLayout

You don't need nested layout like in your xml code. Remove the parent LinearLayout so it becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/icons"
         android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:layout_height="60dp"
         android:padding="5dp" />

      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/item"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:padding="2dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icons"
         android:layout_alignTop="@id/icons"
         android:textColor="#33CC33" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For more flexible layout, you can use [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) or the new [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: Thank you I have marked the last comment as correct

Answer (score 0):

You are using two linear layouts that is not really required here your first linear layout will work fine for you one more point i want to mention do not hard code height and width of any view you can use weightSum provided for linear layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RelativeLayout and inside that use ImageView and TextView and add android:layout_toRightOf  = "@+id/icons" to TextView

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icons"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icons"
        android:textColor="#33CC33" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```